# PHP - refreshing page and showing different rows in a table

Tags: php, arrays, rows

```
 <?php
  //if pageNum isset figure out where to start(7 rows per page * page num +1
   $pageNum = isset($_GET['pageNum']) ? (int)$_GET['pageNum'] : 0;
   $startRow = $pageNum == 0 ? 0 : ($pageNum * 7 + 1);
    $endRow = $startRow + 7;
       $count = 0;
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
if($count >= $startRow)
    echo ' aantal vervangingen: 30';

$row = 1;
  if (($handle = fopen("vervangingen.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

echo '<table border="1">';



while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
fclose($handle);

 }
        if($count == $endRow)
{
    //wait 3 seconds then use javascript to redirect.
    sleep(3);
    echo '<script>window.loaction.href="theurl?pageNum='.($pageNum +1).'"</script>';
}

 }

 ?>
```

I made a table in php which gets the data from a .csv file. My question is, how do i let php show the first 7 rows, then it should refresh the page and show the following 7 rows, there are 30 in total. Once it has shown all the rows, it should still refresh the page and start all over again.

How do I do this? I know how to refresh a php page, but showing 7 rows per refresh is quite hard. Any help?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following (tested) uses PHP sessions and JS setTimeout.
Interesting, but I wonder if I will ever use this effect.
(I was unable to save the $handle as a session variable.)

```
<?php // z1.php is this file, z1.csv is the data file
session_start();
echo <<<EOD
<body onload="setTimeout('f1();',3000);">
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1() { window.location.replace("z1.php"); } 
</script>
EOD;

if (isset($_SESSION['sessrow1st'])) { $row1st = $_SESSION['sessrow1st']; }
else { $row1st = 1; }
$handle = fopen("z1.csv", "r");
if ($handle === false) { exit("open error"); };
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
$rownum = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
  $rownum += 1;
  if ($rownum < $row1st) continue;
  if ($rownum > $row1st+6) break; 
  $numcols = count($data);
  echo '<tr>';
  for ($c=0; $c < $numcols; $c++) {
    if(empty($data[$c])) { $value = "&nbsp;"; }
    else { $value = $data[$c]; }
    echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>'; }
  echo "</tr>\n"; }
echo '</table></body>';
if (feof($handle)) { $rownum = 1; }
fclose($handle);
$_SESSION['sessrow1st'] = $rownum;
?>
```

Comment: This code seems to work for me, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I have one more question actually, how do I exactly set a counter abouv ethe table that shows for example 'showing row 1 to 7' and when it refreshes it says, showing '8 to 14' and so on?

Comment: Insert these 2 lines `$rowlast = $row1st + 6;1` and `echo "rows $row1st to $rowlast <br />\n";` before `echo "<table border='1'>\n";`  to make it say "rows 1 to 7" etc.  But it says "rows 29 to 35" when there are only 30 rows.  So you could read the file twice; the first time just to get the count.  Or you could have a <div> and update the innerHTML at the end when you have the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's setTimeout and a get variable to accomplish this.

```
//if pageNum isset figure out where to start(7 rows per page * page num +1
$pageNum = isset($_GET['pageNum']) ? (int)$_GET['pageNum'] : 0;
$startRow = $pageNum == 0 ? 0 : ($pageNum * 7 + 1);
$endRow = $startRow + 7;
$count = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if($count >= $startRow)
    {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }else{
            echo '<tr>';
        }

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            if(empty($data[$c])) {
               $value = "&nbsp;";
            }else{
               $value = $data[$c];
            }
            if ($row == 1) {
                echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
            }else{
                echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
            }
        }

        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        }else{
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $row++;
    }
    if($count == $endRow)
    {
        //make it dynamic...
        $theUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?pageNum=".($pageNum+1);
        //wait 3 seconds then use javascript to redirect.
        echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){
                 window.location.href="'.$theUrl.'"}, 3000)
              </script>';
    }
    ++$count;

}
```

First step is figure out which page you're on, then display what you want, then use javascript redirect, as php redirect will fail after headers are sent. Also the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function is what controls the wait

Comment: how do I exactly implement that code in my own code? (Sorry for being a noob, this is new for me.). I've tried to put it just above all the code, doesn't seem to work. The output I get is quite weird, first it loads for a while, and then it shows a blank page.

Comment: put all the code you have in the while loop inside the conditional where my comment says 'display what you want here'.

Comment: The table shows properly, but it doesn't refresh or do anything. I've posted the code i'm using now in my own question.

Comment: I updated my code since I first posted it, make sure you are incrementing $count and that location is spelled right. I had errors in my original.

Comment: the one with Javascript's setTimeout or method with sessions?

Comment: I didn't post the other answer. lol. This answer. I originally spelled location wrong and forgot ++$count(the thing at triggers the redirect)

Comment: probably the one with javascript, just asking to be sure.

Comment: still won't do anything, the table is shown (all 30 rows) correct but it won't refresh.

Comment: Th while I posted is your while. don't nest them.

Comment: i've already done that, see this screencap for code i'm using now: http://puu.sh/7Fx5k.png. Can't answer my own question yet.

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you mean with 'The while I posted is your while. don't nest them'

Comment: oh yes, I understand now, stupid that I didn't see it. I'll give it a try

Comment: Also a note, you hav a condition at the top that says if $row==1 echo "<tr>" else echo "<tr>", no point of having a conditional that does the same thing either way. just echo "<tr>";

Comment: Now i get the error Not Found

The requested URL /~xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx/theurl was not found on this server. Theurl should just be array3.php. I type it as array3.php obviously, but it redirects to theurl

Comment: I know, i just can't give out the url since it's from school, so i changed it by xxxxx

Comment: the url is correct, but when I enter it takes a while to load, and then a 404 not found error.

Comment: ok, lets say the page is  www.example.com/my/stuff/array3.php - theurl in the javascript I posted should be like window.location.href="www.example.com/my/stuff/array3.php?pageNum='.($pageNum +1).'"

Comment: There, I changed the code to be dynamic. check the last part where the redirect happens, now I don't need to know the real url and it will work.

Comment: So i don't need to adapt anything anymore?

Comment: It still keeps loading. ;_; Afterwards it just goes to a about:blank page. We can teamview if that would be more comfortable for you.

Comment: isn't it possible to do it all in php?

Comment: you can define a last page variable and make it stop there or display a finished message. Not gonna write the whole thing for you :)

Comment: Why would a finished message or an extra variable be necessary? It doesn't even show the table, before refreshing, I don't really get it.

Comment: figured the link to the .csv wasn't even in it anymore, now it loads ok, but just a blank page.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'll try to figure out what's still wrong I guess.

Comment: fixed it, but the table won't refresh.