# Letting a function execute on a php refresh (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <div style="width: 30em; margin-top: 20px; text-align: center;">
<?php if ( $start > 0 ) { ?>
      <a href="view_members.php?start=<?php echo max( $start - PAGE_SIZE, 0 ) ?>&amp;order=<?php echo $order ?>">Previous page</a>
<?php } ?>
&nbsp;
<?php if ( $start + PAGE_SIZE < $totalRows ) { ?>
      <a href="view_members.php?start=<?php echo min( $start + PAGE_SIZE, $totalRows ) ?>&amp;order=<?php echo $order ?>">Next page</a>
<?php } ?>
    </div>
```

I've got this code that shows values taken from a phpmyadmin database. I have a function next page and previous page as shown in this code above. 4 results are shown. When you click on next page, the following 4 values will be shown. Now my question is: how do i implement the next page function on a automatic PHP refresh, so that 4 different results are shown everytime a refresh takes time.

---

```
define( "PAGE_SIZE", 4 );
```

^ for showing 4 values.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please elaborate what exactly you want

Comment: You'd need to add a `LIMIT` clause to the mysql query you use to get those results

Comment: Just to prevent you from sounding unprofessional in front of other people in the future: There is no such thing as a *phpmyadmin database*. PhpMyAdmin is a tool to administrate MySQL Databases. MySQL is a Database (*thou some argue it is not due to it lacking certain features but that's another story*)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - refreshing page and showing different rows in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583622/php-refreshing-page-and-showing-different-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: @ Guns, there are a certain amount of values in the MySQL database where I'm connecting to. Now i've set the page size on 4, so that 4 values are shown when you go to the webpage. I have a function previous and next page where i can go to the next page with the following 4 values manually. Now my question is, how do i exactly implement the next page function in a automatic refresh, so that I don't have to manually click on next page, but that it simply goes automatic with a automatic refresh.

Comment: @Laurens it is very unclear what you are asking still. You want an automatic refresh (*triggered by what? js timer? behaviour? on-click?*) and on that refresh (*does it have to be the same url or are parameters allowed? if not, why not?*) you want to show the next page? But since you did not react to my answer, cookies or sessions also seem to be out of the picture? Could you clarify?

Comment: I've fixed it already. Your code came in handy though, i'll mark it as a correct answer, thank you for the help! I'm sorry I didn't reply earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use alternate behaviour uppon each refresh you can either use cookies or [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).
For instance, if you want to use sessions, just define a variable in the Session (*let's call it `$pageRefreshCounter` for now*).
Then increment it every time your page refreshes and it is already defined.

```
session_start();
if(array_key_exists('', $_SESSION)) {
  $_SESSION['pageRefreshCounter']++;
}
else {
  $_SESSION['pageRefreshCounter'] = 0;
  $pageRefreshCounter
}
$pageRefreshCounter = $_SESSION['pageRefreshCounter'];
```

Then use `$pageRefreshCounter` for your pagination.